# How to read first word of last line from text file?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

My input file contains `id`, `description Of Item`, `Price` and `date`.

I want to get the `id` of the last line of the file "filename" and increment it.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
var last = File.ReadLines("file name").Last();
id = last[0] + 1;
Console.WriteLine(last[0]);
```

It only returns the first word and not the element example `30`. It gives `3` and not the whole `30`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you place sample data of what you are trying to read.

Comment: item id ,item price,item quantity,item name basically i am implementing Point Of Sale terminal of a store in file system with N-tier architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last` is a string and `last[0]` is the first character of that string. If you want the first word then you'll need to split the string on spaces:

```
string[] words = last.Split(' ');
```

Then you can get the first word:

```
Console.WriteLine(words[0]);
```

You'll need to include more error checking - in case the last line of the file is empty for example, and perhaps cope with more whitespace characters than just a space. There might be tabs:

```
var words = last.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' });
```